# When can I exchange improper integral with derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives, improper-integrals

I want to know when is the below true?
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int^\infty_0f(x,t)\mathrm{d}x=\int^\infty_0\frac{\partial }{\partial t}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$

I have known when is true in normal integral.
The answer is here.

[image]

Comment: Since an improper integral $\int_0^\infty$ is actually itself a limit $\lim_{T \to \infty} \int_0^T$, I guess your question boils down to whether you can interchange the derivative with this limit.

Comment: but when can i do it?@angryavian

Comment: note that when you can interchange, the function inside is of two variables and so it is better notation to use the partial derivative as to not confuse with other derivatives like the total derivative

Comment: ok,i get it correct@HenryLee